# Fusioncharts Xt - Multi-Series Line 2D Chart

Tags: php, fusioncharts

I am trying to create this graph
http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/#line-and-area

If you look at the right row so the third line. (photo 9 of 14).

This is the code im using:

```
$this->load->plugin( 'fusion' );  
        $FC =  FusionCharts("MSLine","620","400");  

         $strParam="palette=2;showvalues=1;numvdivlines=10;drawanchors=0;numberprefix=$;divlinealpha=30;alternatehgridalpha=20;
setadaptiveymin=1;";
           # Set chart attributes 
               $FC->setChartParams($strParam);
           # Add category names
           $FC->addCategory("2001");
           $FC->addCategory("2002");
           $FC->addCategory("2003");
           $FC->addCategory("2004");
           $FC->addCategory("2005");
           # Add category names
          # Add Multi-series  Dataset
           $FC->createMSStDataset();
           # Add Multi-series dataset with in dataset
           $FC->addMSStSubDataset("Product A", "");
            # Add set data for plotting the chart
           $FC->addChartData("30");
           $FC->addChartData("26");
           $FC->addChartData("29");
           $FC->addChartData("31");
           $FC->addChartData("34");
            $FC->createMSStDataset();
           # Add Multi-series dataset with in dataset
           $FC->addMSStSubDataset("Product B", "");
           # Add set data for plotting the chart
           $FC->addChartData("1");
           $FC->addChartData("6");
           $FC->addChartData("123");
           $FC->addChartData("4");
           $FC->addChartData("132");
                echo $FC->renderChart();
```

For some reason Im unable to see 2 lines and I can only see 1 :/
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `MSLine` chart you need to use `addDataset` instead of `createMSStDataset` or `addMSStSubDataset`.

NOTE: $FC->createMSStDataset or $FC->addMSStSubDataset are for `MSStackedColumn2DLineDY` or `MSStackedColumn2D` charts.

Hence, your code will be:

```
       $this->load->plugin( 'fusion' );  
       $FC =  FusionCharts("MSLine","620","400");  

       $strParam="palette=2;showvalues=1;numvdivlines=10;drawanchors=0;numberprefix=$;divlinealpha=30;alternatehgridalpha=20;setadaptiveymin=1;";

       # Set chart attributes 
       $FC->setChartParams($strParam);
       # Add category names
       $FC->addCategory("2001");
       $FC->addCategory("2002");
       $FC->addCategory("2003");
       $FC->addCategory("2004");
       $FC->addCategory("2005");
       $FC->addDataset("Product A", "");
        # Add set data for plotting the chart
       $FC->addChartData("30");
       $FC->addChartData("26");
       $FC->addChartData("29");
       $FC->addChartData("31");
       $FC->addChartData("34");

       $FC->addDataset("Product B", "");
       # Add set data for plotting the chart
       $FC->addChartData("1");
       $FC->addChartData("6");
       $FC->addChartData("123");
       $FC->addChartData("4");
       $FC->addChartData("132");
       echo $FC->renderChart();
```

Reference: http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/?guide-for-web-developers/fusioncharts-php-class/MultiSeriesChart.html

Comment: Thanks! but why can't I make one of the lines to disapper? I saw in thier example you could click on the text under the graph and one of the lines disapper.

Comment: Probably you might be using and earlier version where this was not supported or you are using the FREE product named FusionCharts FREE where this is not supported.

Comment: I just  bought the newest version.. FusionCharts XT